# unsigned int vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a vector template class that looks like this:

```
#ifndef Vector_H
#define Vector_h

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{

public:
//constructor anddestructor
    Vector(unsigned int numberOfElements);
    virtual ~Vector();

    //overloading the [] operator
    T & operator [] (unsigned int index) const;

    //length
    unsigned int length() const;

private:
    T *     data; //the elements in the vector
    unsigned int size; 

};
```

In another class, I use the template class and create a vector. I want to read in lines from a `.csv` file and breakdown the line (i.e customer name, ID, age and gender) and put it into a vector.

Do I need to add an `add` function in my template class to add values into the vector? Am I going about this all wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, you need a function for that.

Comment: Yes you do. But is there any good reason to reinvent the wheel? (Unless it is for study purpose)

Comment: Should your vector support a variable length? If not, your `operator[]` returns a reference and can theirfore be used to modify the elements. If it does support a variable length, you can still get it to increase the size of the underlying array, but it would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: If you need this class only to store your data (not for educational reasons) you should use `std::vector` from `<vector>` instead. But I assume you have written it to learn, so yes, you need method to add data.

Comment: You probably either want your `operator[]` to return a `const` reference, or be non-`const`. The current semantics mean that elements can be changed even on a `const Vector`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Don't forget rule of 0/3/5 (copy constructor, ..).

Comment: a fully functional vector template have lots of gotchas actually, it might not be suited as your first template. maybe complex?

Comment: The include guard is wrong; the code tests for `Vector_H`, then defines `Vector_h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the amount of elements you would add to the vector then that is not needed for your use case. You could just initialize the vector with that size and then use operator `[]` to modify the content. But a [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)-like function will be very usefull.

> Am I going about this all wrong?

Assuming this is for learning purposes not really. If it is not: Yes, use `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: I don't want to use an std::vector because that's too easy and would like to learn how to use a template class. Also I'm going with the angle of assuming the program doesn't know the amount of elements that is going to be added to it.

Comment: In that case, you should add an `add(const T& value)` function (and `add(T&& value)` if you use C++11).

Comment: Okay. Would I also need a function to expand my vector when it gets full?

Comment: @user3452963 Yes, something like reserve/resize should also be in the class, you have something like this in your constructor already if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @user3452963 Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question! - If you like some easier experience with templates I can recommend writing your own big integer class and adding template functions to that.